# Node, express API proxy requests to external API with basic auth header

Tags: node.js, api, express, proxy

I have built a API using node.js and express.
But i need to be able to proxy some requests on a specific route to a external server and show the response from the external server to the clint doing the request.

But i also need to forward the basic auth that the client is send along with the request.

I have tried using the request module like:

```
app.get('/c/users/', function(req,res) {
  //modify the url in any way you want
  var newurl = 'https://www.external.com' 
  request(newurl).pipe(res),

})
```

But it seems to not send the basic auth header because i get "403 Forbidden" back form the external server(www.external.com)

The request im making is looking like:

```
GET http://example.se:4000/c/users/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
X-version: 1
Authorization: Basic bmR4ZHpzNWZweWFpdjdxfG1vcmV1c2*******=
Accept: application/json
Host: example.se:4000
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

And it works if i do the exact same request but against www.external.com directly so there is some issue when doing the proxy in node.

Answer (score 2):

The `request` module is totally unaware of anything that you don't pass explicitly to it. To set the request headers and copy the response headers as well do the following:

```
// copy headers, except host header
var headers = {}
for (var key in req.headers) {
  if (req.headers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    headers[key] = req.get(key)
  }
}
headers['host'] = 'final-host'

var newurl = 'http://final-host/...'
request.get({url:newurl, headers: headers }, function (error, response, body) {
  // debug response headers
  console.log(response.headers)
  // debug response body
  console.log(body)

  // copy response headers
  for (var key in response.headers) {
    if (response.headers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      res.setHeader(key, response.headers[key])
    }
  }
  res.send(response.statusCode, body)
})
```

Comment: Ok so from my understanding i should replace request(newurl).pipe(res),
with:
.get({url:newurl, headers{'Authorization': req.get('Authorization') }}).pipe(res);

But i than get:
 request.get({url:newurl, headers{'Authorization': req.get('Authorization') }
                                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Aaa should have seen that.
hmm still dont get to work as i get 403 Forbidden.
Can i get a log of what is sent?
When i do return console.log(res); i get a lot of things that i dont really understand.

Comment: If you want to see the output instead of pipe-ing the result you can put a callback at the end of the first method call: request.get({...}, function (error, response, body) { console.log(body); res.send(response.statusCode, body) }. See the documentation of the `request` module.

Comment: Is it possible to forward all headers without setting them manually like request.get({url:newurl, headers: req.headers}).pipe(res); But than overwrite the host header?
Because if i pass the host header from request i get a error.

Comment: could you please give advice for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684644/angularjs-expressjs-proxy-post-request-is-pending I will appreciate it very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly passing in the auth details like so

```
request(newurl).auth(username, password).pipe(res);
```

https://github.com/mikeal/request#http-authentication

Comment: But i only get the auth code encoded in the header from the client request like:
Authorization: Basic bmR4ZHpzNWZweWFpdjdxfG1vcmV1c2*******=
So i cant just add username/password. I need to forward this header somehow.

Comment: You can set the header like so
`
    request({
      url: newurl,
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic bmR4ZHpzNWZweWFpdjdxfG1vcmV1c2*******='}}).pipe(res);`

Comment: Sorry im not following you now im not so experienced witd node and express.

I guess i need to than get the header from the request and than pass it to the outgoing request to the external server?