# AngularJS + ExpressJS. Proxy POST request is pending

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, proxy, request

Using AngularJS + Express
I have the following code to proxy my requests to a remote service:

```
app.get('/api.json', function (req, res) {
    req.pipe(request("http://test-api.com/api.json")).pipe(res);
});

app.post('/api.json', function (req, res) {
    req.pipe(request.post("http://test-api.com/api.json")).pipe(res);
});
```

All GET requests works fine, however the **POST** requests are pending in my browser.

Here is how I post:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: '/api.json',
   data: $.param({
       "title": not.title,
       "desc": not.description
  }),  // pass in data as strings
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).success(function () {alert("Success");});
```

What's wrong?

**EDIT:**
Here is the request as seen on the console:
[image]

What should I check to give more information?

Comment: The URLs don't match: the client POSTs to `/notifications.json`, whereas the server codes handles `/api.json`

Comment: Just a typo ... eidted

Comment: if it's pending, the pipe to `request.post` isn't returning anything or is never being reached. if the stream never resumes, the response will never be written to the `res`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I POST from the client (via form) directly to the API, I get a response immediately

Comment: Any new ideas? I'm LOST :(

Comment: What does the post request look like in your console when you do it from a form?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should have mentioned you were using the request library:

https://github.com/mikeal/request

request.post() is expecting the form either as the second parameter:

```
request.post('http://service.com/upload', {form:{key:'value'}})
```

or as a chained call:

```
request.post('http://service.com/upload').form({key:'value'})
```

Because you're not passing it as an argument, request.form() is not making any request at all, waiting for you to call .form(). But since you're not doing that either, **no request ever happens, so no answer is ever returned, and thus your application sees that the request failed without response**. You can see that in the chrome developer tools network tab, where the request will show a "(failed)" status code.

So just obtain the form data from the current request and pass it to request.form and it should work.

For future reference, a debugger would have told you what the mistake was instantly. I recommend the one included with Webstorm, but feel free to use any debugger at all.

Edit: Haven't tried but this is what I would try

```
app.post('/api.json', function (req, res) {
    req.pipe(request.post("http://test-api.com/api.json", {form:req.body})).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: I think I love you! thanks for that amazing help, bounty well deserved!

Comment: I love you too, I don't get 500 rep bounties everyday ;)

Comment: I was about to give up. Glad I found this answer. It should be noted that if you're posting JSON data then you should replace `{form:req.body}` with `{json:req.body}`

Comment: @roberkules thanks for the tip..... {json:req.body} saved me from an issue I was going crazy.