# Nodejs: running ghost in a separate express app and serving it to the main app with a proxy

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, ghost-blog

My setup involves two express apps. The main app gets the blog with a route /blog from the second one using the request module as a proxy. Here are the relevant snippets:

main app: app.js:

```
    var request = require('request');
    app.use('/blog', function(req,res) {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8082'+require('url').parse(req.url).path;
        req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
    });
```

Ghost's app is set up to run in a directory:

app.js:

```
    ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {
    ghostServer.start();
    });
```

config.js:

```
    url: 'http://localhost:8082/blog'
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but I cannot seem to log in to the admin console. Checking network requests shows that all the POST requests are pending and eventually fail. Once it fails, I get this in both apps:

```
POST /blog/ghost/api/v0.1/authentication/token - - ms - -
```

I've tried different proxy modules, but all yield same results. I found some info about pending POST results here [AngularJS + ExpressJS. Proxy POST request is pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684644/angularjs-expressjs-proxy-post-request-is-pending) but the setup is a little different. Help would really be appreciated, thank you!